# Maximo Anywhere using dojo mixin on the WorkOrderObject onInitialize fails to render WorkList

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I'm trying to set the values of some custom local attributes in the Work Execution application. Using Scott's recommended approach of using dojo mixin ([Work Log Default](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/b43fc5ba-d118-4a30-9e1f-449305a21e55/attachment/0318fb33-5415-49c4-9c30-e12c1eadc241/media/WORKAsDefaultLogType.pdf)) to implement custom logic while still utilizing the defined IBM code for the WorkOrderObject causes the list view to not display any records. Initially I thought I had done something incorrectly, but it seems like the issue is specifically using the dojo mixin with this line in the WorkOrderObject that calls another function.

`this.refreshClassDescription(workOrder);`

If I comment this line out in the out of the box WorkOrderObject, my customizations work and the work list renders properly. I saw some dojo documentation about using safeMixin ([Dojo safeMixin](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare-safemixin)) which is supposed to help with some issues related to using mixin but doesn't seem to resolve this issue (I get the same results whether I use mixin or safeMixin).

I've verified it's not an issue inside the method getting called because if I comment out all the logic in that method it still fails using mixin. I need a way to be able to add my own logic to the WorkOrderObject but can't get it to work in this scenario (using mixin for all the other functions works as expected). I can't modify the out of the box javascript files because future patches from IBM will cause our customizations to be lost.

Is there a good way to combine the out of the box object and our custom object and have it support `this.` functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Steven, is the underlying problem that that function doesn't exist, or that the ***this*** keyword doesn't exist in that scope?

If it's the second, you might simply need to initialize a local variable self to store the this reference in your mixin code.

Answer (score 0):

Scott was right, it was a scope problem. I ended up reading a lot about JavaScript `this.` to better understand the problem. [JavaScript Binding](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations) in particular was an extremely helpful read. I previously had `var sg_originalInitialize = WorkOrderObject.onInitialize;`. By using `var sg_originalInitialize = WorkOrderObject.onInitialize.bind(WorkOrderObject);`, the `this.` commands will know to use the WorkOrderObject as intended (and of course would still work even if a `this.` doesn't exist). That article lists a few other options but this is pretty clean and apparent from a code perspective.